# How to use google place API in android app effectively

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

There are multiple options to use with `AutoCompleteTextView`,

- calling api to server and let server control suggesting auto complete places proxying google APIs, considering control to throttle the rate
- calling directly from client to google API on raw rest API and parsing response JSON
- is there a Java client for google place API already available that abstracts parsing and other parts and respects current location to add context to what user might be looking for and other contextual data about user to fine tune search ? if so an example would be great pointer

what is the common practice around here

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question, I have developed both a pure Java client for the Google Places API ([Sprockets for Java](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets)) and an Android library project ([Sprockets for Android](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets-android)) that builds on top and provides classes like [GooglePlaceAutoComplete](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets-android/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/widget/GooglePlaceAutoComplete.html) and [GooglePlacesLoader](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets-android/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/content/GooglePlacesLoader.html).

After setting up the library, adding a `GooglePlaceAutoComplete` widget to your app is just a single tag in a layout (example below).  In your Activity or Fragment, you can also register an `OnPlaceClickListener` that is called when the user chooses a suggested place.

```
<net.sf.sprockets.widget.GooglePlaceAutoComplete
    android:id="@+id/place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need some documentation to make decisions. A good place to start is, of course, the [google places api for android](https://developers.google.com/places/android/) section. I think you will find here all the info you need.

> calling api to server and let server control suggesting auto complete
>   places proxying google APIs, considering control to throttle the rate
>
> calling directly from client to google API on raw rest API and parsing
>   response JSON

I would go for the the first option if I would have an application that will need some limitations of request and data gathering about maybe who/where/when your requests are made, this being(I think) the best solution to control your billing and keep yourself the track of requests. The second solution it is not bad either, but keep in mind that you will enconde your google places api key in your application! More about the billing and usage limitations [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android/usage).

> is there a Java client for google place API already available that
>   abstracts parsing and other parts and respects current location to add
>   context to what user might be looking for and other contextual data
>   about user to fine tune search ? if so an example would be great
>   pointer

On the same website you will find [samples](https://developers.google.com/places/android/code-samples) of how to use google places api in your applications. For autocomplete check [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceComplete) out.